# Spring app deployed on Tomcat7 hangs and doesn't load forever

Tags: spring, memory-leaks, tomcat7, classloader, server.xml

My Applications loads fine and suddenly when accessed after a while doesn't load and keeps looping until I manually stop and restart the service.

```
http-bio-80-exec-20" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00000000073f4800 nid=0xc48 waiting on condition [0x0000000010bff000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000757b2e5e0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    "http-bio-80-exec-16" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000da95000 nid=0xe18 runnable [0x000000000fefc000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:300)
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:106)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:315)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:260)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:185)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:102)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:873)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1491)
        - locked <0x00000007582a3358> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:406)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:335)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:315)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:855)
        - locked <0x000000075742b020> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:884)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:336)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy45.getDisplayNameForUid(Unknown Source)
        at com.java.service.fieldAccess.AccessRulesServiceImpl.getDisplayNameForUid(AccessRulesServiceImpl.java:59)
        at com.java.controller.StudentUtility.getId(StudentUtility.java:94)
        at com.java.controller.StudentUtility$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d009f0a4.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:618)
        at com.java.controller.HomeController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7694ad53.getId(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor88.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.invokeModelAttributeMethods(ModelFactory.java:123)
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:614)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
```

AFter researching based on the stack trace,this the query that seem to be the one that are sending the thread into Blocked state at two context
context 1:

```
String login = getLogin(authentication);


        FormUser user = ars.getUserByUid(login);//lock at this line
 private String getLogin(Authentication authentication) {
            Object authenticationUserDetails = authentication.getPrincipal();
            String str = authenticationUserDetails.toString();
            logger.info("AUTHDETAILS:" + str);
            MyUserDetails details = (MyUserDetails)authenticationUserDetails;
            String username = details.getUsername(); //87845!!
            String password = details.getPassword();
            logger.info("Username: " + details.getUsername());

            return username;
        }
```

context 2: `

```
 map.put("canImportData", ars.getUserByUid(principal.getName()).getRoleTemplate().getTemplateName().contains("Admin"));`
```

The query in question:

```
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public FormUser getUserByUid(String uid) {
        return(FormUser) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from FormUser where uid = " + Integer.valueOf(uid)).uniqueResult();
    }
```

Comment: Please post some configuration. Generally this is a database issue and the fact that there are no more connections. Which generally is due to wrong or absent transaction configuration or messing around with connections without returning them to the pool.

Comment: @M.Deinum placed the server.xml configuration as part of the questiion.if you need more configuration please specify.Direct my attention to the root cause and the steps i need to follow to fix the problem and make the app available at all times.

Comment: Your server.xml isn't useful, it is about the application. Post some configuration, code etc. Also I suggest using the search as there are several other questions regarding applications that become unresponsive.

Comment: @M.Deinum,I have posted both the configuration and controller code.I have also included the student utility class code at ModelAttribute("id") getId which seem to cause a timed exception saying could not open connection in qa.Please help get to the root of the problem and steps to fix it.

Comment: @M.Deinum,i also enabled the spring logging to diagnose any connection issue.is the stack trace shown above the cause Please direct me in the right path in figuring out the cause and fixing the solution.Thanks

Comment: No and is isn't an exception it is only trace logging. As mentioned show some of your actual service, dao code. Also what is that `StudentUtility`? I couldn't see it anywhere?

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum,I have added the studentdao.impl which is the core dao class that has most of the workflows attached from the dispatcher servlet.I hope this Dao helps or i have others,which i can post if u need them,Student utility is a controller class.

Comment: For starters they way you are constructing your queries is wrong. You should NEVER NEVER NEVER use string concat to create queries, use placeholders and `setParameter` to set the queries. Benefit is that the queries can now be cached by the server. You should also not catch exceptions as that breaks proper tx management. On your pool switch maxWait to something else as -1, which means wait forever, make it a sensible number. I would also recommend HikariCP over Commons DBCP (the first is imho a better connection pool). Also a dao using another dao is strange that should be the service level.

Comment: When your application hangs (unresponsive) kill the server and make sure that you get stack traces from that status before killing it. That way can see where it hangs or what it was doing.

Comment: Another thing that is flawed is your cache why on earth are you trying to invent your own? Let Hibernate do that for you by enabling 2nd level caching, your current solution has problems especially when you start lazy loading things or updating things. Hibernate has very good caching integration I strongly suggest using that instead of trying to invent your own solution.

Comment: @M.Deinum,I have so many threads in the waiting or parking state,i have included only one cause of space constraint.Will changing the maxWait=10 fix the problem.also i dont know how and where i can manage the thread pool count as most of the threads seem to be locked on the thread pool executor.

Comment: @M. Deinum The thread that you see above which is in runnable state after a little time gets into blocked state ,blocked at the queries that i listed above,which seem to be pretty straight forward.Please give your insight and help me resolve this iisue at the application level,i would then go for the Hiraki CP if needed..

Comment: @M.Deinum:please look at the trace and throw your insight..i found the query to be fairly simple on which the thread seems to be waiting to locck and then locking it.i don't understand how to trouble shoot it

Comment: Please help give ur suggestions ..i've no idea,if its the connections or a bug in the application or a memory leak or all from the stack trace.

Comment: There isn't anything obvious so the only thing you can do is look for lost connections. The fact that it hangs here doesn't mean the problem is here, it is just the manifestation of the issue i.e. your pool dried out or something is keeping a lock on the database.

Comment: How do you look for lost connections,i thought thread dump would be more than enough to identify the root cause of the issue.how does one find if something is holding a lock over database.what other ways to troubleshoot and find the root cause

Comment: By walking to a DBA and ask for help to detect locks. Identifying bottlenecks isn't a java thing only you need the whole landscape.

Comment: @M.Deinum:Walked over to te DBA and he says no potential locks,but says doesn't find any connections from the application to the oracle database,when the application is frozen.He declares it's not a databse lock issue,but an issue of synchronization in spring.Doesn't appreictae having annotation Transactional for read query's

Answer (score -1):

To start, lets check your java version and verify its on your PATH:

java -version

Then give this a whirl:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

and call gradle clean war and deploy that to your tomcat instance. You'll want to verify that your build version of java (7 for example) matches your tomcat expected version in the catalina.sh file which looks are JAVA_HOME followed by JRE_HOME.

Comment: the points of failure are probably in the hibernate bean coming online or the JDBC driver or the DB itself as others have commented on. I would disable those beans and try to just stand up the application itself before integrating with the database.

Comment: I'm not using any build tool as such not even maven ,and hence have no experience with gradle.also, tomcaton prod is set up on windows server 2008 is managed by server manager.I would request you to be more clear and elaborte please.direct me towards fixing the issue.